# Spring oauth includes stacktrace in response body when a request is sent

Tags: spring-mvc, spring-security, oauth-2.0, spring-security-oauth2, spring-rest

In the OAuth 2 code,an error such as requesting a refresh token using an invalid token value ends up generating a response that includes the stack trace, and I don't see a way to configure or disable this extra information.

When i hit the api url i get the below stack trace, while it should have shown only 401 unauthorized

```
   "stackTrace": [
{
  "methodName": "translate",
  "fileName": "DefaultWebResponseExceptionTranslator.java",
  "lineNumber": 53,
  "className": "org.springframework.security.oauth2.provider.error.DefaultWebResponseExceptionTranslator",
  "nativeMethod": false
},
{
  "methodName": "doHandle",
  "fileName": "AbstractOAuth2SecurityExceptionHandler.java",
  "lineNumber": 59,
  "className": "org.springframework.security.oauth2.provider.error.AbstractOAuth2SecurityExceptionHandler",
  "nativeMethod": false
},
{
  "methodName": "commence",
  "fileName": "OAuth2AuthenticationEntryPoint.java",
  "lineNumber": 54,
  "className": "org.springframework.security.oauth2.provider.error.OAuth2AuthenticationEntryPoint",
  "nativeMethod": false
},
{
  "methodName": "sendStartAuthentication",
  "fileName": "ExceptionTranslationFilter.java",
  "lineNumber": 186,
  "className": "org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter",
  "nativeMethod": false
},
{
  "methodName": "handleSpringSecurityException",
  "fileName": "ExceptionTranslationFilter.java",
  "lineNumber": 161,
  "className": "org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter",
  "nativeMethod": false
},
{
  "methodName": "doFilter",
  "fileName": "ExceptionTranslationFilter.java",
  "lineNumber": 131,
  "className": "org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter",
  "nativeMethod": false
},
{
  "methodName": "doFilter",
  "fileName": "FilterChainProxy.java",
  "lineNumber": 342,
  "className": "org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain",
  "nativeMethod": false
},
{
  "methodName": "doFilter",
  "fileName": "SessionManagementFilter.java",
  "lineNumber": 103,
  "className": "org.springframework.security.web.session.SessionManagementFilter",
  "nativeMethod": false
},
{
  "methodName": "doFilter",
  "fileName": "FilterChainProxy.java",
  "lineNumber": 342,
  "className": "org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain",
  "nativeMethod": false
},
{
  "methodName": "doFilter",
  "fileName": "SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.java",
  "lineNumber": 154,
  "className": "org.springframework.security.web.servletapi.SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter",
  "nativeMethod": false
},
{
  "methodName": "doFilter",
  "fileName": "FilterChainProxy.java",
  "lineNumber": 342,
  "className": "org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain",
  "nativeMethod": false
},
{
  "methodName": "doFilter",
  "fileName": "RequestCacheAwareFilter.java",
  "lineNumber": 45,
  "className": "org.springframework.security.web.savedrequest.RequestCacheAwareFilter",
  "nativeMethod": false
},
{
  "methodName": "doFilter",
  "fileName": "FilterChainProxy.java",
  "lineNumber": 342,
  "className": "org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain",
  "nativeMethod": false
},
{
  "methodName": "doFilter",
  "fileName": "OAuth2AuthenticationProcessingFilter.java",
  "lineNumber": 131,
  "className": "org.springframework.security.oauth2.provider.authentication.OAuth2AuthenticationProcessingFilter",
  "nativeMethod": false
},
{
  "methodName": "doFilter",
  "fileName": "FilterChainProxy.java",
  "lineNumber": 342,
  "className": "org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain",
  "nativeMethod": false
},
{
  "methodName": "doFilterInternal",
  "fileName": "WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.java",
  "lineNumber": 50,
  "className": "org.springframework.security.web.context.request.async.WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter",
  "nativeMethod": false
},
{
  "methodName": "doFilter",
  "fileName": "OncePerRequestFilter.java",
  "lineNumber": 107,
  "className": "org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter",
  "nativeMethod": false
},
{
  "methodName": "doFilter",
  "fileName": "FilterChainProxy.java",
  "lineNumber": 342,
  "className": "org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain",
  "nativeMethod": false
},
{
  "methodName": "doFilter",
  "fileName": "SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.java",
  "lineNumber": 87,
  "className": "org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter",
  "nativeMethod": false
},
{
  "methodName": "doFilter",
  "fileName": "FilterChainProxy.java",
  "lineNumber": 342,
  "className": "org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain",
  "nativeMethod": false
},
{
  "methodName": "doFilterInternal",
  "fileName": "FilterChainProxy.java",
  "lineNumber": 192,
  "className": "org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy",
  "nativeMethod": false
},
{
  "methodName": "doFilter",
  "fileName": "FilterChainProxy.java",
  "lineNumber": 160,
  "className": "org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy",
  "nativeMethod": false
},
{
  "methodName": "invokeDelegate",
  "fileName": "DelegatingFilterProxy.java",
  "lineNumber": 344,
  "className": "org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy",
  "nativeMethod": false
},
{
  "methodName": "doFilter",
  "fileName": "DelegatingFilterProxy.java",
  "lineNumber": 261,
  "className": "org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy",
  "nativeMethod": false
},
{
  "methodName": "doFilter",
  "fileName": "FilterInstanceWrapper.java",
  "lineNumber": 195,
  "className": "com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.FilterInstanceWrapper",
  "nativeMethod": false
},
{
  "methodName": "doFilter",
  "fileName": "WebAppFilterChain.java",
  "lineNumber": 91,
  "className": "com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterChain",
  "nativeMethod": false
},
{
  "methodName": "doFilter",
  "fileName": "WebAppFilterManager.java",
  "lineNumber": 928,
  "className": "com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterManager",
  "nativeMethod": false
},
{
  "methodName": "invokeFilters",
  "fileName": "WebAppFilterManager.java",
  "lineNumber": 1025,
  "className": "com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterManager",
  "nativeMethod": false
},
{
  "methodName": "handleRequest",
  "fileName": "WebApp.java",
  "lineNumber": 3748,
  "className": "com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebApp",
  "nativeMethod": false
},
{
  "methodName": "handleRequest",
  "fileName": "WebGroup.java",
  "lineNumber": 304,
  "className": "com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebGroup",
  "nativeMethod": false
},
{
  "methodName": "handleRequest",
  "fileName": "WebContainer.java",
  "lineNumber": 962,
  "className": "com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.WebContainer",
  "nativeMethod": false
},
{
  "methodName": "handleRequest",
  "fileName": "WSWebContainer.java",
  "lineNumber": 1662,
  "className": "com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.WSWebContainer",
  "nativeMethod": false
},
{
  "methodName": "ready",
  "fileName": "WCChannelLink.java",
  "lineNumber": 195,
  "className": "com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.channel.WCChannelLink",
  "nativeMethod": false
},
{
  "methodName": "handleDiscrimination",
  "fileName": "HttpInboundLink.java",
  "lineNumber": 459,
  "className": "com.ibm.ws.http.channel.inbound.impl.HttpInboundLink",
  "nativeMethod": false
},
{
  "methodName": "handleNewRequest",
  "fileName": "HttpInboundLink.java",
  "lineNumber": 526,
  "className": "com.ibm.ws.http.channel.inbound.impl.HttpInboundLink",
  "nativeMethod": false
},
{
  "methodName": "processRequest",
  "fileName": "HttpInboundLink.java",
  "lineNumber": 312,
  "className": "com.ibm.ws.http.channel.inbound.impl.HttpInboundLink",
  "nativeMethod": false
},
{
  "methodName": "ready",
  "fileName": "HttpInboundLink.java",
  "lineNumber": 283,
  "className": "com.ibm.ws.http.channel.inbound.impl.HttpInboundLink",
  "nativeMethod": false
},
{
  "methodName": "sendToDiscriminators",
  "fileName": "NewConnectionInitialReadCallback.java",
  "lineNumber": 214,
  "className": "com.ibm.ws.tcp.channel.impl.NewConnectionInitialReadCallback",
  "nativeMethod": false
},
{
  "methodName": "complete",
  "fileName": "NewConnectionInitialReadCallback.java",
  "lineNumber": 113,
  "className": "com.ibm.ws.tcp.channel.impl.NewConnectionInitialReadCallback",
  "nativeMethod": false
},
{
  "methodName": "futureCompleted",
  "fileName": "AioReadCompletionListener.java",
  "lineNumber": 165,
  "className": "com.ibm.ws.tcp.channel.impl.AioReadCompletionListener",
  "nativeMethod": false
},
{
  "methodName": "invokeCallback",
  "fileName": "AbstractAsyncFuture.java",
  "lineNumber": 217,
  "className": "com.ibm.io.async.AbstractAsyncFuture",
  "nativeMethod": false
},
{
  "methodName": "fireCompletionActions",
  "fileName": "AsyncChannelFuture.java",
  "lineNumber": 161,
  "className": "com.ibm.io.async.AsyncChannelFuture",
  "nativeMethod": false
},
{
  "methodName": "completed",
  "fileName": "AsyncFuture.java",
  "lineNumber": 138,
  "className": "com.ibm.io.async.AsyncFuture",
  "nativeMethod": false
},
{
  "methodName": "complete",
  "fileName": "ResultHandler.java",
  "lineNumber": 204,
  "className": "com.ibm.io.async.ResultHandler",
  "nativeMethod": false
},
{
  "methodName": "runEventProcessingLoop",
  "fileName": "ResultHandler.java",
  "lineNumber": 775,
  "className": "com.ibm.io.async.ResultHandler",
  "nativeMethod": false
},
{
  "methodName": "run",
  "fileName": "ResultHandler.java",
  "lineNumber": 905,
  "className": "com.ibm.io.async.ResultHandler$2",
  "nativeMethod": false
},
{
  "methodName": "run",
  "fileName": "ThreadPool.java",
  "lineNumber": 1814,
  "className": "com.ibm.ws.util.ThreadPool$Worker",
  "nativeMethod": false
}
  ],

     "additionalInformation": null,
  "oauth2ErrorCode": "unauthorized",
 "httpErrorCode": 401,
  "summary": "error=\"unauthorized\", error_description=\"An Authentication     object was not found in the SecurityContext\"",
  "message": "An Authentication object was not found in the SecurityContext",
  "localizedMessage": "An Authentication object was not found in the SecurityContext"
  }
```

This is my pom.xml :

```
    <properties>
    <spring.version>4.1.2.RELEASE</spring.version>
    <jackson.version>1.9.13</jackson.version>
    <javax.validation.version>1.1.0.Final</javax.validation.version>
        <spring.security.version>3.2.5.RELEASE</spring.security.version>
</properties>

<dependencies>

  <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.validation</groupId>
        <artifactId>validation-api</artifactId>
        <version>${javax.validation.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <!-- <dependency>
        <groupId>junit</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
        <version>3.8.1</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency> -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-web</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-jdbc</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
        <artifactId>jackson-core</artifactId>
        <version>2.4.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
        <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
        <version>2.4.1.1</version>
    </dependency>

        <!-- Spring Security -->
        <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-context-support</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-security-web</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.security.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-security-config</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.security.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.security.oauth</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-security-oauth2</artifactId>
        <version>1.0.0.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>

        <dependency>
        <groupId>commons-httpclient</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-httpclient</artifactId>
        <version>3.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>log4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
        <version>1.2.17</version>
    </dependency>

<!--    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
        <version>1.6.1</version>
    </dependency> -->

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>slf4j-log4j12</artifactId>
        <version>1.6.1</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.mail</groupId>
        <artifactId>mail</artifactId>
        <version>1.5.0-b01</version>
    </dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
    <artifactId>commons-lang3</artifactId>
    <version>3.0</version>
</dependency>
```

This is my spring-servlet.xml

```
    <beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p" xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
xmlns:task="http://www.springframework.org/schema/task"
xsi:schemaLocation="
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans    
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-4.0.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.0.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/task
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/task/spring-task-3.0.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc-4.0.xsd">

<!-- <mvc:annotation-driven content-negotiation-manager="contentNegotiationManager" 
    /> -->
<mvc:default-servlet-handler />
<mvc:annotation-driven />
<context:component-scan base-package="com.peoplcheck.*" />
<task:annotation-driven />
<mvc:resources mapping="/resources/**" location="/resources/" />

<bean id="dataSource" class="org.springframework.jndi.JndiObjectFactoryBean">
    <property name="jndiName" value="jdbc/peoplecheck" />
</bean>
```

This is my web.xml:

```
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>people-check</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    <async-supported>true</async-supported>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>people-check</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
    <listener>
    <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
</listener>
    <context-param>
    <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
    <param-value>  
        /WEB-INF/spring-servlet.xml,  
        /WEB-INF/spring-security.xml
    </param-value>
</context-param>

<!-- Spring Security -->

<filter>
    <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
    <filter-class>org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy</filter-class>
</filter>

<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>
```

This is my spring-securiy.xml :

```
<!-- This is default url to get a token from OAuth -->
<http pattern="/oauth/token" create-session="stateless"
    authentication-manager-ref="clientAuthenticationManager"
    xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security">
    <intercept-url pattern="/oauth/token" access="IS_AUTHENTICATED_FULLY" />
    <anonymous enabled="false" />
    <http-basic entry-point-ref="clientAuthenticationEntryPoint" />
    <!-- include this only if you need to authenticate clients via request 
        parameters -->
    <custom-filter ref="clientCredentialsTokenEndpointFilter"
        after="BASIC_AUTH_FILTER" />
    <access-denied-handler ref="oauthAccessDeniedHandler" />
</http>

<!-- This is where we tells spring security what URL should be protected 
    and what roles have access to them -->
<http pattern="/**" create-session="never"
    entry-point-ref="oauthAuthenticationEntryPoint"
    access-decision-manager-ref="accessDecisionManager"
    xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security">
    <anonymous enabled="false" />
    <intercept-url pattern="/**" access="ROLE_APP" />
    <custom-filter ref="resourceServerFilter" before="PRE_AUTH_FILTER" />
    <access-denied-handler ref="oauthAccessDeniedHandler" />
</http>


<bean id="oauthAuthenticationEntryPoint"
    class="org.springframework.security.oauth2.provider.error.OAuth2AuthenticationEntryPoint">
    <property name="realmName" value="test" />
</bean>

<bean id="clientAuthenticationEntryPoint"
    class="org.springframework.security.oauth2.provider.error.OAuth2AuthenticationEntryPoint">
    <property name="realmName" value="test/client" />
    <property name="typeName" value="Basic" />
</bean>

<bean id="oauthAccessDeniedHandler"
    class="org.springframework.security.oauth2.provider.error.OAuth2AccessDeniedHandler" />

<bean id="clientCredentialsTokenEndpointFilter"
    class="org.springframework.security.oauth2.provider.client.ClientCredentialsTokenEndpointFilter">
    <property name="authenticationManager" ref="clientAuthenticationManager" />
</bean>

<bean id="accessDecisionManager" class="org.springframework.security.access.vote.UnanimousBased"
    xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans">
    <constructor-arg>
        <list>
            <bean class="org.springframework.security.oauth2.provider.vote.ScopeVoter" />
            <bean class="org.springframework.security.access.vote.RoleVoter" />
            <bean class="org.springframework.security.access.vote.AuthenticatedVoter" />
        </list>
    </constructor-arg>
</bean>

<authentication-manager id="clientAuthenticationManager"
    xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security">
    <authentication-provider user-service-ref="clientDetailsUserService" />
</authentication-manager>


<!-- This is simple authentication manager, with a hardcoded user/password 
    combination. We can replace this with a user defined service to get few users 
    credentials from DB -->
<authentication-manager alias="authenticationManager"
    xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security">
    <authentication-provider>
        <user-service>
            <user name="beingjavaguys" password="spring@java" authorities="ROLE_APP" />
        </user-service>
    </authentication-provider>
</authentication-manager>

<bean id="clientDetailsUserService"
    class="org.springframework.security.oauth2.provider.client.ClientDetailsUserDetailsService">
    <constructor-arg ref="clientDetails" />
</bean>


<!-- This defined token store, we have used inmemory tokenstore for now 
    but this can be changed to a user defined one -->
<bean id="tokenStore"
    class="org.springframework.security.oauth2.provider.token.InMemoryTokenStore" />

<!-- This is where we defined token based configurations, token validity 
    and other things -->
<bean id="tokenServices"
    class="org.springframework.security.oauth2.provider.token.DefaultTokenServices">
    <property name="tokenStore" ref="tokenStore" />
    <property name="supportRefreshToken" value="true" />
    <property name="accessTokenValiditySeconds" value="420" />
    <property name="clientDetailsService" ref="clientDetails" />
</bean>

<bean id="userApprovalHandler"
    class="org.springframework.security.oauth2.provider.approval.TokenServicesUserApprovalHandler">
    <property name="tokenServices" ref="tokenServices" />
</bean>

<oauth:authorization-server
    client-details-service-ref="clientDetails" token-services-ref="tokenServices"
    user-approval-handler-ref="userApprovalHandler">
    <oauth:authorization-code />
    <oauth:implicit />
    <oauth:refresh-token />
    <oauth:client-credentials />
    <oauth:password />
</oauth:authorization-server>

<oauth:resource-server id="resourceServerFilter"
    resource-id="test" token-services-ref="tokenServices" />

<oauth:client-details-service id="clientDetails">
    <!-- client -->
    <oauth:client client-id="restapp"
        authorized-grant-types="authorization_code,client_credentials"
        authorities="ROLE_APP" scope="read,write,trust" secret="secret" />

    <oauth:client client-id="restapp"
        authorized-grant-types="password,authorization_code,refresh_token,implicit"
        secret="restapp" authorities="ROLE_APP" />

</oauth:client-details-service>

<sec:global-method-security
    pre-post-annotations="enabled" proxy-target-class="true">
    <!--you could also wire in the expression handler up at the layer of the 
        http filters. See https://jira.springsource.org/browse/SEC-1452 -->
    <sec:expression-handler ref="oauthExpressionHandler" />
</sec:global-method-security>

<oauth:expression-handler id="oauthExpressionHandler" />
<oauth:web-expression-handler id="oauthWebExpressionHandler" />
```

Answer (score 0):

One of your dependencies may be affecting a default Spring setting:

For yml files, update with:

```
spring:
    error:
        include-stacktrace: never
```

For properties files, update with:

```
spring.error.include-stacktrace=never
```

After restarting with this setting, the `stackTrace` field should disappear. 
I found this Spring Boot commit that appears to have introduced the setting: https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/commit/a1e0f01103f2ba1d2417e946850ac3e47f820b9b